# ReactJS sending data from Form select via axios.post

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-bootstrap

I'm building simple CRUD web application with React for my "Fleet manager" with SpringBoot API. I'm stuck with how to  execute `axios.post` method to add Car. Code for `Car` component below:

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { Button, Card, Form, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faSave , faUndo} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import axios from 'axios';

class Car extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.initialState;
        this.carChange = this.carChange.bind(this);
        this.submitCar = this.submitCar.bind(this);
    }

    initialState = {
        carBrand:'', 
        carModel:'', 
        carManufactureYear:'', 
        carType:'', 
        engineCapacity:'', 
        enginePower:'', 
        plateNumber:'', 
        isTaken:'', 
        companyId:'', 
        companies: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('localhost:8080/company')
            .then(res => {
                const companies = res.data;
                this.setState({companies});
                console.log(res.data);
            })
    }

    submitCar = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const car = {
            carBrand: this.state.carBrand,
            carModel: this.state.carModel,
            carManufactureYear: this.state.carManufactureYear,
            carType: this.state.carType,
            engineCapacity: this.state.engineCapacity,
            enginePower: this.state.enginePower,
            plateNumber: this.state.plateNumber,
            isTaken: this.state.isTaken,
            companyId: this.state.companyId
        };

        axios.post("localhost:8080/car", car)
            .then(res => {
               if (res.data != null) {
                   this.setState(this.initialState);
                   alert("Samochód dodany pomyślnie");
               }
            });

    }

    carChange = e => {
        this.setState({
        [e.target.name]:e.target.value
        });
    }

    resetCar = () => {
        this.setState(() => this.initialState)
    }

    render(){
        const {
            carBrand, 
            carModel, 
            carManufactureYear, 
            carType, 
            engineCapacity, 
            enginePower, 
            plateNumber, 
            isTaken, 
            companyId
    } = this.state;

        return(
            <Card className={"border border-dark bg-dark text-white"}>
                <Card.Header>Add a car</Card.Header>
                <Form onReset={this.resetCar} onSubmit={this.submitCar} id="carFormId">
                    <Card.Body>
                            <Form.Row>
                                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridBrand">
                                    <Form.Label>Car brand</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control required autoComplete="off"
                                        type="text" name="carBrand"
                                                  value={carBrand}
                                                  onChange={this.carChange}
                                        className={"bg-dark text-white"}
                                        placeholder="Put car brand" />
                                </Form.Group>
                                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridModel">
                                    <Form.Label>Car model</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control required autoComplete="off"
                                        type="text" name="carModel"
                                                  value={carModel}
                                                  onChange={this.carChange}
                                        className={"bg-dark text-white"}
                                        placeholder="Put car model" />
                                </Form.Group>
                            </Form.Row>

                            // Other inputs for rows

                    </Card.Body>
                    <Card.Footer style={{"textAlign":"right"}}>
                        <Button variant="success" type="submit">
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSave}/> Wyślij
                        </Button> {' '}
                        <Button variant="danger" type="reset">
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUndo}/> Reset
                        </Button>
                    </Card.Footer>
                </Form>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}

export default Car;
```

This is data I get from `axios.get(localhost:8080/car)` :

```
{
    "idCar": 1,
    "carBrand": "Skoda",
    "carModel": "Fabia",
    "carManufactureYear": 1999,
    "carType": "Cieżarowy",
    "engineCapacity": "2.4",
    "enginePower": "105",
    "plateNumber": "WW 0017Y",
    "isTaken": 0,
    "company": {
        "idCompany": 1,
        "name": "KFC",
        "nip": "5260211104",
        "address": {
            "idAddress": 1,
            "country": "Polska",
            "zipCode": "82-300",
            "city": "Elbląg",
            "street": "Płk. Dąbka",
            "buildingNumber": "152"
        },
    "addressId": null
    },
    "companyId": null
},
```

and data from `axios.get(localhost:8080/company)` :

```
{
    "idCompany": 1,
    "name": "KFC",
    "nip": "5260211104",
    "address": {
        "idAddress": 1,
        "country": "Polska",
        "zipCode": "82-300",
        "city": "Elbląg",
        "street": "Płk. Dąbka",
        "buildingNumber": "152"
    },
    "addressId": null
},
```

Now what I'm trying to reach is:  in `Car` component user provide necessary data, pick company from `Form.Control as="select"` represented with it's name

```
{this.state.companies.map(company =>
     <option key={company.idCompany}>{company.idCompany}</option> )}
```

When i send this data via axios.post method it gives me error like this :

```
xhr.js:177 POST localhost:8080/car/ 500

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

When I send companyId with `Form.Control type="text"` it works perfecty fine. What should I do to send idCompany with name from `Form.Control as="select"`?

Comment: Look at the backend logs to see why it returned 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is: i was trying to send company.name as companyId, solution was to add `value={company.idCompany)` to

```
{this.state.companies.map(company =>
                        <option key={company.idCompany}>{company.idCompany}</option> )}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are chaining .then() method, it will return a promise. To solve this issue, you have two options:

1. Remove "car" from axios.post() method. You shouldn't pass "car" as a second argument if you are using Promise. here is an example

   axios.post("localhost:8080/car")
   .then(res => {
   if (res.data != null) {
   this.setState(this.initialState);
   alert("Samochód dodany pomyślnie");
   }
   }).catch(e => console.log(e));

   2. Passing "Car" as a second argument and removing Promise:
      axios.post("localhost:8080/car", car => {
      if (car.data != null) {
      this.setState(this.initialState);
      alert("Samochód dodany pomyślnie");
      }
      })